# SQL: Ordenar por colunas de outra tabela

Tags: sql, sqlite

Tenho uma tabala de utilizadores, e outra com as respectivas pontuações, preciso de selecionar da tabela de pontuações apenas utilizadores que vivam num certo pais.

O pais esta defendido na tabela utilizadores, cada tabela tem um id único correspondente a cada utilizador.

Como poderei filtrar a lista de pontuações tendo em conta o pais definido na tabela utilizadores?

Comment: Apesar da descrição não estar clara deduzo que na tabela pontuações você tem um campo que identifica o utilizador que obteve tal pontuação. Neste caso basta fazer um JOIN entre estas duas tabela utilizando este campo utilizador.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sem você informar os campos da tabela fica difícil montar uma query mais específica.
Mas pelo exemplo abaixo acredito que você possa entender o que deve ser feito.

```
SELECT u.CamposDaTabelaUtilizador, p.CamposDaTabelaPontuacao
  FROM utilizadorers AS u
  INNER JOIN pontuacao as p ON u.IDutilizador = ID.pontuacao;
```